# RHEL patch management via SCCM

Tags: windows, redhat, sccm

I'm looking for advice with RHEL patch management in a Windows environment.

We run an Intranet that is completely disconnected from the Internet.  Currently the network spans a half dozen sites with ~80 servers (most virtual using Hyper-V) and a few hundred Win 7 workstations.  Most servers are 2008R2.  We now have a single virtual RHEL 5 server that is required for us to run specialized security scanning software (no choice).  We currently use SCCM 2007R2 for all our patch management but now we also need to patch the RHEL server.

I've researched setting up an offline yum repository but from what I read it would require another RHEL server?  I've also read that SCCM 2012R2 will patch RHEL but I'm having a hard time understanding how to get updates in a similar way to WSUS for a disconnected system.  I've also looked at Chef and Puppet but it seems like overkill to manage a single RHEL server.

Comment: Normally this is a pretty bad move, but depending on what the RHEL server is doing and what it's performance requirements are, you could set the server up as its own offline yum repo. Might be easier than trying to monkey with SCCM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im pretty sure you need to update to SCCM 2012R2 to manage LINUX/UNIX clients - and even then you will need to add the extra client management packs

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39360

SCCM upgrade/migration is pretty easy these days assuming your setup isn't too complex.

Im sure someone will correct me if im wrong but my understanding is that you are essentially using an application/package script to remotely run whatever bash command you would run to update so it might still need an offline repository even with SCCM in the loop in the same way as your WSUS server would work.